# django forms: two form models in one <form> with a foreign key

Tags: django, django-forms

In creating a new user, I am using two models: `User` (from django.contrib.auth.models) and `Privilege` with a `OneToOne` relation:

```
class Privilege(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    privCreate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    privDelete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
```

Two form models:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', )

class PrivilegeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    privCreate = forms.BooleanField(label='Create a document')
    privDelete = forms.BooleanField(label='Delete a document')
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Privilege
        fields = ('privCreate', 'privDelete', ...)
```

In the template, there are two template `{% for %}` loops, one for `UserForm`, and one for `PrivilegeForm`, enclose by one `<form>` tag.

And finally, the view:

```
userForm = UserForm(data=request.POST)
privilegeForm = PrivilegeForm(data=request.POST)
if userForm.is_valid() and privilegeForm.is_valid():
    user = userForm.save()
    privilegeForm.save()
```

However, I have no idea how to set the value of `user` in the Privilege model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use pass in False for the commit kwarg into the privilegeForm's save call. This will return the privilege object without saving it. Then you can assign the user object to it that was created, and then call save on privilege to commit to the database.

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

```
userForm = UserForm(data=request.POST)
privilegeForm = PrivilegeForm(data=request.POST)
if userForm.is_valid() and privilegeForm.is_valid():
  user = userForm.save()
  privilege = privilegeForm.save(commit=False)
  privilege.user = user
  privilege.save()
```